# How to access a Tkinter widget from another thread in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm using the threading module (python 3) and tkinter.ttk to create a simple clock.

this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from threading import Thread
import time

running = True

def tick():

    while running:
        t = time.localtime()
        temp = str(t.tm_hour) + ":" + str(t.tm_min) + ":" + str(t.tm_sec)
        clock.config(text=temp)

def exit():

    global running
    running = False
    win.destroy()


tick_thread = Thread(target=tick)
tick_thread.start()

win = Tk()

win.geometry("100x100")
win.resizable(False, False)
win.title("Clock")

clock = Label(win, text="")
clock.pack()

win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit)

win.mainloop()
```

but I get an error saying clock in not defined (tick_thread) because the "tick thread" can't access the "clock" label widget. So my question is: how do I share the widget across threads? and if I override the window closing protocol will everything close properly?  Thanks.

Comment: See question 'Sharing data between threads in Python'

Comment: Don't start the thread until after you've created the widget.

Comment: Thank you both for the help, I moved the thread declaration to the end of the program just like Bryan said and it works now.